How can I push a newly instantiated mutex into std::vector<std::mutex>?
I can initialize a std::mutex with auto mtx = std::mutex(); but it seems impossible to push one into std::vector<std::mutex>:
both
    std::vector<std::mutex> vec;
    vec.push_back(std::mutex());

and
    std::vector<std::mutex> vec;
    auto mtx = std::mutex();
    vec.push_back(std::move(mtx));

gave me error error: use of deleted function ‘std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex&)’
How do I push a std::mutex into std::vector<std::mutex>?

You can't. std::mutex is neither copyable nor movable.

Which means you can't change the size of your vector after creating it.

How do I push a std::mutex into std::vectorstd::mutex? -- This sounds like an XY Problem.

I think your basic issue is a faulty design, why do you even think storing mutexes (or having a lot of them) is a good idea? You should really carefully think about where you need a mutex (usually one  or at most a few per instance of a class). So be thankful the standard made it so that mutexes are not copyable/movable, this is really telling you you are trying to do something that is probably not going to end well.

std::mutex is a non-movable and non-copyable object; how would one move it when another thread has it locked? One way to make a workaround this issue is to wrap it via a pointer.
Say, use std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::mutex>> vec; and create new mutexes via std::make_unique<std::mutex>(). Alternatively, instead of std::vector use std::unique_ptr<std::mutex[]> when the number mutexes is fixed.

No don't give the advice to wrap mutexes like this. The non-copyable - non-movable properties of mutexes are there to warn developers that doing this is a bad idea.
Mutexes should be part of internal datastructures (classes) and those classes should manage the instances + keep the locks on them as short as possible while still guarantee threadsafety of the invariants of those classes.

@PepijnKramer he does not specify why he needs a vector of mutexes. While it is an odd choice, likely caused by a bigger design error in this case, it is not my place here to judge or get involved in that. Only how to solve this minor issue.

fair enough. I just get worried when I see people trying to things like this ;)
